# Construct 1 variable function from given 2 variable function

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable-definitions, variable

Given a function f[x , y].
The definition of f is not self-describing.  (f was defined with objects other than f.)
Then I want to construct a function g[x] such that
f[x,y] and g[x][y] are the same, **and the definition of g does not contain f.**

For example, given

```
In[1]  f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3
```

I've tried

```
In[2] g[x_]:=f[x,#]&
```

Checked an example

```
In[3]  f[3,2] == 17 == g[3][2]
Out[3] True
```

Looks okay so far but

```
In[4]  Definition[g]
Out[4] g[x_] := f[x, #1] &
```

**The definition of g contains f. (fail)**
What I want is a function h such that

```
In[4] Definition[h]
Out[4] x^2+#1^3&
```

I've tried Evaluate/Activate/FullSimplify, to g, but not worked.

Can you construct a function let's say, ToOperator,
such that ToOperator[f] wil produce h ?

(ToOperator produces a warning message if the definition of f is self-describing.
The generalization of ToOperator will be of course, multiple variable function as input + user choose some of those variables)

Answer (score 7):

What you want is called "currying".

Not involving new operators you may try:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3
g[x_] = Evaluate[f[x, #]] &;

f[3, 2] == 17 == g[3][2]
?? g
```

[image]

However, MMA has a special operator `CurryApplied` for this:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3
g = CurryApplied[f, 2];
f[3, 2] == 17 == g[3][2]
?? g
```

[image]

You may want to also look at `OperatorApplied`.

Comment: To quote the OP (re `CurryApplied` solution): "**The definition of g contains f. (fail)**".